# capture process that keeps changing PID

Tags: linux, xargs, proc

i have the following:

```
netstat -anp | grep ':36084 ' | grep CLOSE_WAIT | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d \/ -f1 | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}"
```

this returns a process PID

i want to inspect and find out more about the actual process, where it is being executed from and which is the trigger?

Comment: and your question is?

Answer (score 1):

ok, i got it

```
netstat -anp | grep ':36084 ' | grep CLOSE_WAIT | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d \/ -f1 | grep -oE "[[:digit:]]{1,}" | ls -l /proc/$(</dev/stdin)/exe
```